# Mysql community server :enter the root account password - on windows

Tags: mysql

[image]
I am installing **Mysql community server** and during this step it asks me to enter the password for the root account and i don't know how to solve this problem. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is asking you to set the root password. Its a new password. Set the password to something that is memorable (or written on a post-it note).

Comment: i'm trying to enter any password but it doesn't work : " Could not connect to mySQL, the service is possibly down or the host is unreachable"

Comment: If you've already completed an install look at [staring a mysql service](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/8.0/en/windows-start-service.html).